# Alternate register/login with facebook details

Tags: facebook, api, app-secret

The application on my forum (alternate registration information) asks for

Facebook App ID; - i have this

Facebook Secret; - i have this

Facebook Page Url; - what is this?

Facebook Plugins default language; english (UK)

Site Domain; - what is this?

When i try and login i get API error 191?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your Site Domain to allow Facebook login on your site. You can login to Facebook in your App just via one specified Domain.

if your apps URL is

> "http://www.EXAMPLE.com/myFbApp"

then fill this value in facebook page url and Site Domain will be

> "EXAMPLE.com"